# Summation with condition

Tags: summation, index-notation

Can anyone explain how to do the following sum with condition:
$$L = \sum_{i=1,w_i\geq0}^M w_i x_i$$

or
$$L = \sum_{i=1,w_i\geq0}^M w_i x_i + \sum_{i=1,w_i<0}^M w_i y_i$$

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Presumably you have a list of values $w_i$ of varying signs and you seek to split the sum according to those signs.  Where is the confusion?

Comment: @lulu what to do with negative values $w_i$?

Comment: In the top sum?  Ignore them.  You are only summing over indices $i$ for which $w_i≥0$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. got it now.